# SwiftUI set views height dynamically in relation to parent

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to create a bunch of views like this:

```
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { reader in
      VStack {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
          HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            ForEach(0..<24) { hour in
              VStack {
                Rectangle()
                  .fill(Color.orange)
                  .frame(
                    height: model.height(hour, containerHeight: reader.size.height), alignment: .bottom)
                Text("\(hour)").font(.caption2)
              }
            }
          }
        }
        Text("Hour of Day")
      }
    }
  }
```

The view's model produces a height value from this:

```
  func height(_ hour: Int, containerHeight: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    let steps = CGFloat(hourSteps[hour] ?? 0)
    let cgMax = CGFloat(maxSteps)
    return (steps/cgMax)*containerHeight*10
  }
```

Which works but I notice that the height value from GeometryReader changes resulting in some views that are proportional to one height and some that are proportional to another.

I'm not sure GeometryReader is the correct thing or that I'm using it or SwiftUI correctly, thank you for reading.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I want those Rectangles to be proportionally sized in height related to the parent, at a value determined by their height to each other. 
Each Rectangle represents some ratio of data, like 300/500, so I want that percent to be the height of the Rectangles.

Comment: So, a bar graph. What is model.height? you don't have a [Minimal Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Yes, a way quicker way to say that, lol sorry, still on the first cup of coffee :).

Comment: Added the model's height method

Comment: It is changing because of the content size inside is changing, a result of the ScrollView and ForEach loop. This is expected behavior. A simple fix is to add a "Subtraction" from the added rectangle. Perhaps adding a private value to your model, that tracks the total height passed in, then subtract that value from the reader's height after the first. You may be able to move your reader inside the ForEach loop so that it only contains the child view itself.

Answer (score 0):

Without an MRE, I can onle show you a working example. A couple of points. First, the `GeometryReader` is in the wrong place. It should be on the bar itself, as that is the element that needs to know the available height. Second, when doing views like these, decompose them into individual views. It becomes a lot easier to debug your views that way.

As a result, I refactored the code that does the bar into its own view. That view contains the `GeometryReader`. When making bars, I like to have a whole height element, and then use an `.overlay()` of the percentage height element, with a `.bottom` alignment on the `.overlay()`. Once you have the basics, you can simply place it in to your `ForEach`. Obviously, this element can be made more customizable, but injecting different colors, etc.

```
struct BarGraphView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        ForEach(1..<25) { hour in
                            VStack {
                                BarView(percentage: CGFloat(hour)/CGFloat(24))
                                Text("\(hour)")
                                    .font(.caption2)
                                    .lineLimit(1)
                                    
                            }
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 500)
                        }
                    }
                    Text("Hour of Day")
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}

struct BarView: View {
    
    let percentage: CGFloat
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { reader in
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.gray) // if you make this clear, there is no background.
                .frame(width: reader.size.width)
                .overlay(
                    VStack {
                        Rectangle()
                            .fill(Color.orange)
                    }
                        .frame(height: percentage * reader.size.height),
                    alignment: .bottom)
        }
    }
}
```